# Passing arguments values to shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using the following script to purge cache from cdn,

```
#!/bin/bash

##  API keys ##
zone_id=""
api_key=""
login_id=""
akamai_crd=""

## URL ##

urls="$1"
[ "$urls" == "" ] && { echo "Usage: $0 url"; exit 1; }

echo "Purging $urls..."

curl -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/${zone_id}/purge_cache" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: ${login_id}" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: ${api_key}" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data "{\"files\":[\"${urls}\"]}"

#echo "CF is done now purging from Akamai ..."

echo  "..."

curl -v -s https://api.ccu.akamai.com/ccu/v2/queues/default -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"objects":["$urls"]}' -u $akamai_crd
```

The 1st part for cloudflare is working fine the 2nd part when I pass it to Akamai

```
["$urls"]
```

I keep getting an error and it's passing the url as an argument it returns the variable itself ($urls) not the arg value.

I ran the script as following:

```
sh +x  script.sh  url
```

Any advise here?

Comment: I would suggest to this: SCRIPTNAME=$(basename "$0") if [ $# != 1 ]
then
 echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME url"
 exit
fi   $urls="$2"

Comment: its working fine for the 1st curl , in the 2nd curl its not

Comment: Then change your second curl-command like this: --data "{\"files\":[\"${urls}\"]}"

Comment: thats worked for me thanks

Comment: please mark my answer. THX :)

Comment: Are you always passing a *single* URL as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i would change this:

```
SCRIPTNAME=$(basename "$0") 
...
if [ $# != 1 ] then 
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME url" 
    exit 
fi 

$urls="$1"
```

Change your second curl command as the following (you need to escape the quotes):

```
--data "{\"files\":[\"${urls}\"]}"
```

Comment: $2 was an fast copy and paste failure from me.

Comment: basename "$0" -> you get the scriptname wihtout "./"

Comment: FWIW, common convention is to print usage with a raw `$0`. See `ls --help` versus `/bin/ls --help`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid creating JSON by hand like this; you can't guarantee that the resulting JSON is properly escaped. Use a tool like `jq` instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

##  API keys ##
zone_id=""
api_key=""
login_id=""
akamai_crd=""

## URL ##

url=${1:?Usage: $0 url}

headers=(
  -H "X-Auth-Email: $login_id"
  -H "X-Auth-Key: $api_key"
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
)

purge_endpoint="https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/${zone_id}/purge_cache"

echo "Purging $url..."

jq -n --arg url "$url" '{files: [$url]}' | 
  curl -X DELETE "$purge_endpoing" "${headers[@]}" --data @-

#echo "CF is done now purging from Akamai ..."

echo  "..."

jq -n --arg url "$url" '{objects: [$url]}' | 
  curl -v -s -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @- -u "$akamai_crd"
```